# How to make Firefox mobile cache videos?

Tags: android, html, firefox, caching, video

I am working on an end-to-end video ad serving web application. The application serves ad videos using the `<video>` tag of HTML5, in a loop. The client is in my control, only requirement being that it must be an Android device. I have found Firefox on Android to work best for displaying videos using HTML5, hence I am using it for the client. I am using webm videos, if that matters. The videos are 3MB to 30MB in size. I have setup the web server to send the videos with `Expires` set to 1 day.

Unfortunately, Firefox on Android does not seem to be caching the videos for very long. The videos seem to be cached for about 2-5 minutes, but seem to be downloaded again after that. This is not ideal for me as I would like to conserve bandwidth required to download ads, and it also prevents lags while playing the videos.

Firefox on desktop does cache the videos properly.

Is there any way to get Firefox on Android to cache the videos?

Comment: Options: 1) Make the videos smaller. 2) Use [Appcache](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html).

Comment: @robertc, thanks for your answer. I am looking at Appcache right now. Regarding making videos smaller -- how would that help? I have already increased the `browser.cache.max_entry_size` in the Firefox settings and it didn't help.

Comment: It will conserve the bandwidth required to download them.